# how to implement a query so that i get the result as required

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with these values. 
I want to query this table with limit of 5 but i want total row always to be part of resultset.

Table Description:

```
  id  desc  value

  1    A     100
  2    B     200
  3    C     300
  4    D     400
  5    E     500
  6    F     600
  7    G     700
  8    H     800
  9    I      900
  10  Total 1000
```

i want to know whether its possible.

Comment: How is the `total` = 1000 for those 9 values in your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a little messy in a single query. Maybe you can use a UNION query:

```
SELECT `id`, `value` FROM `table` LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT 'Total', SUM(`value`) AS `value` FROM `table`
```

This will yield 5 rows from the table and a 'Total' row under.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
SELECT id, `desc`, value FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(id), 'Total', SUM(value) FROM table;
```

However, If you need to limit the selection from the table to only 5, you have to use `LIMIT` inside two subqueries like so:

```
SELECT id, `desc`, value
FROM
(
  SELECT id, `desc`, value FROM table1
  ORDER BY id
  LIMIT 5
) t
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(id), 'Total', SUM(value) 
FROM
(
  SELECT id, `desc`, value FROM table1
  ORDER BY id
  LIMIT 5
) t;
```

For your sample data this will give you:

```
| ID |  DESC | VALUE |
----------------------
|  1 |     A |   100 |
|  2 |     B |   200 |
|  3 |     C |   300 |
|  4 |     D |   400 |
|  5 |     E |   500 |
|  5 | Total |  1500 |
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3226c/8)

**Note that:** The `Total` row will be the sum of all the previous `value` values, however, in your sample data it is not the total.

Answer (score 0):

you can alternatively use `WITH ROLLUP`. but the downside is one column is missing: the `ID`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(`desc`, 'TOTAL') `desc`, SUM(`value`) Value
FROM Description
GROUP BY `desc`
WITH ROLLUP
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7051a/4)